# Not Displaying Date correctly in Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have a webpage that displays a a table of data pulled back from a sql server view via entity framework and WCF Services.

On my sql server view one of the columns is a Date Field.  I am having some difficulty getting it to display without the time part on my page (the time part if not there on the DB but from reading it seems as it is a DateTime property when I generate my entity view the time part will be added.

So basically on my model I have the following (obv the names are just mocked here):

**Model**

```
public List<MySqlView> MySqlView { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
model.MySqlView = MyWCFService.GetMeAlltheData(
                      //pass in some values start date, end date
                  );
```

So on this I can see everything I want returning fine and then I pass the model to my view.

To build up my table then in the View I am doing the following:

**cshtml**

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.MySqlView)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-data">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </td>
                    //More stuff in table close loop
```

I have tried `item.Date.ToShortDateString()` but that throws exception

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: do you have to use a helper? I've had more success displaying data (esp dates) w/o helper

Answer (score 0):

Having a ViewModel class separate the model from the view solves virtually all interface issues. The more I work with MVC, the more I realize a better approach is MVVmC. This is a good example of why. Instead of strongly typing to the model itself, create a ViewModel that provides to the view a string property with the correctly formatted date value using `MyDateTimeItem.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DateTime.cshtml in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates with following content

```
@model DateTime

@Html.Label("", Model.ToShortDateString())
```